# check if Latlng is inside polygon

Tags: android, google-maps, android-location, android-maps

I'm drawing Polygon on city in order to check if current position is inside this polygon or not, and i'm doing that with below code:-

```
 ArrayList<LatLng> polyLoc = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
polyLoc.add(new LatLng(24.643932, 46.297718));
    polyLoc.add(new LatLng(24.695098, 46.555897));
    polyLoc.add(new LatLng(24.921971, 46.476246));
    polyLoc.add(new LatLng(25.147185, 46.366383));
    polyLoc.add(new LatLng(25.155886, 47.249409));
    polyLoc.add(new LatLng(24.929444, 47.346913));
    polyLoc.add(new LatLng(24.691355, 47.106587));
    polyLoc.add(new LatLng(24.449060, 47.219197));
    polyLoc.add(new LatLng(24.293947, 46.973377));
    polyLoc.add(new LatLng(24.641436, 46.299092));
```

And i checking if the current position is inside this polygon or not by this way :-

```
if (hasPermission() && gpsTracker.canGetLocation()) {
        if (isPointInPolygon(new LatLng(gpsTracker.getLatitude(), gpsTracker.getLongitude()), polyLoc)) {
            cash.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            cashIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            cash.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            cashIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "reservationDialog: " + gpsTracker.getLatitude() + gpsTracker.getLongitude());
    }
```

here is my isPointInPolygon method :

```
private boolean isPointInPolygon(LatLng tap, ArrayList<LatLng> vertices) {
    int intersectCount = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < vertices.size() - 1; j++) {
        if (rayCastIntersect(tap, vertices.get(j), vertices.get(j + 1))) {
            intersectCount++;
        }
    }

    return ((intersectCount % 2) == 1); // odd = inside, even = outside;
}

private boolean rayCastIntersect(LatLng tap, LatLng vertA, LatLng vertB) {

    double aY = vertA.latitude;
    double bY = vertB.latitude;
    double aX = vertA.longitude;
    double bX = vertB.longitude;
    double pY = tap.latitude;
    double pX = tap.longitude;

    if ((aY > pY && bY > pY) || (aY < pY && bY < pY)
            || (aX < pX && bX < pX)) {
        return false; // a and b can't both be above or below pt.y, and a or
        // b must be east of pt.x
    }

    double m = (aY - bY) / (aX - bX); // Rise over run
    double bee = (-aX) * m + aY; // y = mx + b
    double x = (pY - bee) / m; // algebra is neat!

    return x > pX;
}
```

I don't know why it's not working, what i'v missed here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why your code didn't work.

But you can use `PolyUtil.containsLocation (new LatLng (latitude, longitude), polyLoc, true)`

This would return false if the position outside the polygon.

Comment: It returns always true in my case, either outside or inside, don't know why

Comment: Yes. I have added the first point of array in last as well which makes it closed. That's worked. Thanks

Comment: @MuhammadNoman You're welcome, feel free to upvote the answer :

Answer (score 0):

In my project, I'm doing this calculation on the server. I'm using **geolib** library to do this. If you need to calculate in your app. You can get the logic from the library.

Library:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/geolib

Git: https://github.com/manuelbieh/Geolib